# Increasing xrandr maximum

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr

I've got a 4K laptop screen connected to a Dell 5K monitor. The Dell uses two Display Ports, and presents as 2 monitors; one with resolution up to 4K, and another with resolutions of 848x480 and 2560x2880. They way to get 5K on the external monitor seems to be to run both of its ports at the 2560 resolution. However, if I try to use xrandr to set those values, it tells me that the required resolution is greater than the max. The output from xrandr is given below. Is there a way I can raise the maximum from 8192 to something larger?

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7680 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  60.00  
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   2560x2880     59.98    29.99  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   848x480       59.74 +
   2560x2880     59.98    29.99  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: what you would use is the framebuffer or `--fb` flag for that, like `xrandr --fb 16384x16384` but thats as the name says the framebuffer not the real resolution which you would need to set seperatly.

Comment: I tried --fb 8960x2880 (and also 8960x8960). I get told that screen size cannot be larger than 8192x8192 (desired size [what I tried]). Any ideas?